How can I compile s3fs-fuse in static mode?
Steps to compile s3fs-fuse :

apt-get update
apt-get install -y build-essential libfuse-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libxml2-dev mime-support automake libtool pkg-config
git clone https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse.git
cd s3fs-fuse
./autogen.sh
./configure --prefix=/usr --with-openssl --enable-static

Got ERROR:
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --enable-static
expecting to compile s3fs-fuse in static mode.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
